# Want to recognize a workflow Texture painting

Tags: texturing, uv, workflow, texture-painting

Is there a name or denomination for the workflow/practice of superposing image and paint threw it.

link of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3Eu-GKhb4U&t=1153s

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information to clarify the question. The question as it stands can easily be googled

Comment: I edited the question to be understundable sry

Comment: That is using a Brush Texture set to 'Stencil' which let s you see the image and rotate and scale it to match your desired paint target. https://youtu.be/QLI1uY2id20?t=664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be referring to [Projective Texturing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_texture_mapping), which blender lets you do with paint mode and it works quite well.

There's a lot of settings for how the texture/image can be used while painting, but you can read all about it [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/texture.html)

Comment: Thx, sorry for the vague question that seam super cool i dont understand everything about projective texturing but i begin to understand what use you can have and why the image is display in transparency in the video but i dont understand if the objectif of it is just painting precisely the image texture or be able to use all the space of the image, maybe both

Comment: i just check out some tutorial thats insanely cool thank you very much !